# How to set constraints for iPhone X device alone

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, iphone-x

I have a logo in the storyboard set to a top constraint of value 28 and it works for all devices. On iPhone X device it merges with the camera bar on the top. If i increase the top constraint it affects the other devices. How do i set a constraint only for iPhone X alone?

Comment: Have you tried constraining the view to the Safe Area? The Safe Area changes to account for the notch on the iPhone X.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default Xcode provides you with a `Safe Area` upon project creation.

[image]

Here, I've added a `UIView` with the following constraints. Take note of how the constraints are pinned to the `Safe Area`, and not the `Superview`.
[image]

Running the app, you'll see that the view respects the status bar across all devices.

Hope this helps with the issue you're having...

Comment: Surprisingly, this is the simplest explanation I've found for handling the iPhone X constraints.